# Show two UIAlertController objects continuously using completion block

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to show two UIAlertController's instances **continuously**, which is like this code block below.

```
func showAlerts() {
    let alertA = UIAlertController(title: "Alert A", message: "This is alert a...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertB = UIAlertController(title: "Alert B", message: "This is alert b...", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let alertButton1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let alertButton2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alertA.addAction(alertButton1)
    alertA.addAction(alertButton2)
    alertB.addAction(alertButton1)
    alertB.addAction(alertButton2)

    self.present(alertA, animated: true) { 
        self.present(alertB, animated: true, completion: { 
            debugPrint("alerts are all shown")
        })
    }
}
```

I expect this code to show each alert continuously, which means `alertB` shows after `alertA`. But `alertB` doesn't appear as I expect, with warnings on console saying;

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f7ffde0ace0>  on <ContinuousUIAlertController_Experiment.ViewController: 0x7f7ffdd092d0> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7f7ffde09f90>
```

If I remember correctly, multiple UIAlertController objects cannot be existed at the same time. So I somehow understand what the warning above tells.

So, then, how can I implement continuous alert showing using completion of `UIViewController::present(_:animated:completion:)` or with nearly the same logic? (I prefer not to use UIAlertAction's handler)

If there is a solution, please let me know.
I'm struggling with this problem for a few days and I've not addressed yet.

Comment: What's the point of showing two alerts at the same time? The user will only be able to see one. Why not show the 2nd after the user dismisses the 1st?

Comment: You can have multiple custom views added as subviews with buttons.

Comment: @rmaddy showing two alerts continuously, not at the same time. Yes, I want to show the 2nd alert after disappeared the 1st, somehow by using completion block.

Comment: @iAviator can you explain a bit more for details? I'd grad if there's some code example!

Comment: Your code makes no attempt to show the alerts one after the other, over and over. It only attempts to show both at the same time, and only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show 2 uialettcontrol at 1time.

But you can show 2nd uialettcontrol on 1st one's uialeraction.

For example

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message:
            "Hello, world!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive,handler: { action in
            self.pressed()
        }))

func pressed()
{
    print("you pressed")
}
```

On pressed event you can write code for 2nd uialettcontrol.

Comment: This should work, but the OP mentioned not to use UIAlertAction's handler

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It actually works, but as @ronatory mentioned, I prefer not to use UIAlertAction's handler, such as completion of `UIViewController::present(_:animated:completion:)`.

Comment: Did you got any other solution? then kindly share.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using topController. Just call topController.present instead of self.present. By doing this way, you can present an alert over an alertController.

Get the top controller as such:

```
func getTopController() -> UIViewController? {
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }
    return nil
}
```

And use it as,

```
getTopController().present(alertA, animated: true) { 
    getTopController().present(alertB, animated: true, completion: { 
        print("alerts are all shown")
    })
}
```

Comment: "you can present an alert over an alertController" But that is not what the OP asked to do.

Comment: Still we can show two alertcontrollers continuously using this method @matt